# Replace NA in a variable by their value with other observation

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this one :

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 5, 3),
                 B = c("a", "b", "c", "d", NA, "b", NA, NA, NA ))
```

I want ro remplace this dataframe by the vlue recuperated in the other observation.
For example, in the variable A, for 1 correspond "a" in the variable B; so NA should be remplaced by a.
But for 5, we can't conclude so I keep NA.
How could I do this, I'm stuck.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
df$B <- with(df, ave(as.character(B), A, FUN= function(x)
                  ifelse(is.na(x), na.omit(x), x)))
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ ,B:=ifelse(is.na(B), na.omit(B), B) , A]
```

Or a variant would be

```
setDT(df)[,B:=if(any(is.na(B))) unique(na.omit(B)),  A][]
```